# How to solve Apex / Ords Configuration of Static Files

Tags: oracle-apex-18.2

I'm using Oracle XE 18C on a Windows platform.  I installed Apex 18.2 and then installed ORDS 18.4.  I followed the instructions in section 1.3.4.1 in the install guide for **Apex 18.2** https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmig/configuring-Oracle-REST-data-services.html#GUID-AD38DE06-A560-4D6D-BD50-6E5A8E513BBF.strong text

I created two users: with the following commands:

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=XEPDB1;
create user APEX_LISTENER identified by (password) account unlock;
create user APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER identified by (password) account unlock;
```

When I was prompted for "Enter the Apex static resource location" I responded with **C:\app\product\apex\images**

The install went without an error.  I looked at all the logs in C:\Users(my_username).  Not a single mention of "error" or "warning".

In the Apex install guide, section 4.6 it instructs to copy the Apex images folder to ORDS.  I copied **C:\app\product\apex\images** to **C:\app\product\ords\images**.  Then I ran **@apex_rest_config.sql** from SQL Plus.  It seemed to complete OK.

When I attempt to access Apex through a browser (**localhost:9090/ords/apex**) I receive a popup error: "There are issues with the configuration of the Static Files in your environment.  Please consult "Configuring Static File Support" section in the Application Express Install Guide."

If I click OK on the prompt I can continue on to the Apex logon screen.  I'm able to login and get to the first screen.  However I want to address the error before proceeding further.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: which Application Server are you using ?

Comment: Oracle's Apex 18.2

Comment: no i am asking where are you deploying ORDS. is it weblogic, tomcat, embedded???

Comment: Hello.  I see now.  It's embedded.

Comment: XE 18C, Apex 18.02 and Ords 18.4 are all installed on the same Windows 10 platform.

Comment: Ok. When you run java –jar ords.war make sure you give the right apex image path.

Comment: Thanks Phanny.  I gave it C:\app\product\apex\images  That's where the images reside.  I tripple-checked in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing XE 18C In edited the TNSNAMES.ORA file:

```
XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xepdb1)
    )
  )
```

Then I realized that I had to install Apex 18.2 and ORDS in the same PDB Container (XEPDB1).  Here are the steps from SQLPlus:

```
Alter Session set container=XEPDB1;
@apexins SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/ -- (Note: This creates users APEX_180200, APEX_PUBLIC_USER, APEX INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER and FLOWS_FILES in the XEPDB1 container.  Only APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN_USER is Open.  All others are locked.) 
Select Status from dba_registry Where Comp_ID = 'APEX'; -- (This should return “VALID” if apex was properly installed.)
@apxchpwd -- (Note: this will change the password for the Apex ADMIN account) 
Alter Profile DEFAULT limit password_life_time unlimited;
Alter User APEX_PUBLIC_USER Identified by password account unlock;
Alter User ANONYMOUS account unlock; 
Alter User FLOWS_FILES account unlock;
Alter User APEX_180200 account unlock;
Commit;
@apex_rest_config.sql -- (Note: This creates APEX_LISTENER and APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER in the XEPDB1 container and gives them the password you specify in this step.)
@apex_epg_config.sql C:\app\product
Alter User APEX_LISTENER account unlock;
Alter User APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER account unlock; 
Alter Session set container = CDB$ROOT;
Alter User XDB account unlock;
Exit
```

From there I installed ORDS 18.4

```
java -jar ords.war install advanced
Configuration Data = C:\app\product
Database Service Name = XEPDB1
Apex Static Resource Location = C:\app\product\apex\images
```